# foreach array displaying result

Tags: php, foreach

I have been looking at this code etc for so long that I am now confusing myself - not good

I have foreach of

```
  foreach($sort_order as $sort)
    {
      echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($sort['sorder']);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
```

That gives me a result of:

```
string(2) "20"
string(2) "10"
```

How can I return this so I can do `value="<?php echo $someValue; ?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'sorder' is a key in your array I would try the following:

```
foreach($sort_order as $key => $sort) {
    echo '<pre>';
        if($key == "sorder") {
            echo $sort[$key];
        }
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I now get Undefined offset: 0

Comment: The array is:  ["sorder"]=>
  string(2) "20"

Comment: The array only has one element in it??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only displaying they key. I'm assuming your array is of type associative.

To traverse associative arrays in PHP, follow this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
     echo "[" . $key . "]" . " = " . $value . "<br />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but...

```
<?php 
  $val = array();
  foreach($sort_order as $sort) {
    $val[] = $sort['sorder'];
  } 
?>

<p>value = <?php echo $val[0]; ?></p>
<p>value = <?php echo $val[1]; ?></p>
```